# Give an enumeration procedure for the set L = {ww: w ∈ {0, 1}*}

Tags: enumeration

Enumeration process: How would I list what is here?

So, explain how to list a word with a word using only {0,1}*?

Now I'm confusing with WW.  Is there a way to just list out just 1W?

How should I go about this?

Thank you.

Comment: This is completely off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`w` represents a string consisting of ones and zeros. The string can be also the empty one and in general `w` can have arbitrary length. `ww` means a string that concatenated to itself. If for example `w = 001`, then `ww = 001001`. So to enumerate all such strings, you need first to enumerate each possible string and then concatenate it to itself.

In python we can start enumerating like this:

```
from itertools import product
for ndigits in xrange(4):
    for s in product("01", repeat=ndigits):
        w = "".join(s)
        print w + w
```

Output:

```
00
11
0000
0101
1010
1111
000000
001001
010010
011011
100100
101101
110110
111111
```